# Microsoft Access: Runtime error 3142. Characters found after end of SQL statement

Tags: microsoft-access

This is my code from Microsoft Access. I am trying to do a search of a certain keyword in a subform. I get the following error: **runtime error 3142. Characters found after end of SQL statement**. When I debug, the following line is highlighted: `Me.subMain_db.Form.RecordSource = SQL`. Can anyone give me an idea of how to fix this? Thank you! :)

```
Option Compare Database  
Option Explicit   
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()  

Dim SQL As String   
SQL = "SELECT main_db.creator_id, main_db.cw_id, main_db.supplier FROM main_db; WHERE creator_id LIKE ' * " & Me.txtKeywords & " * ' "  

Me.subMain_db.Form.RecordSource = SQL  
Me.subMain_db.Form.Requery 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT main_db.creator_id, main_db.cw_id, main_db.supplier FROM main_db; WHERE creator_id LIKE ' * " & Me.txtKeywords & " * ' "
Me.subMain_db.Form.RecordSource = SQL
Me.subMain_db.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Remove the semi-colon in this line:

```
SQL = "SELECT main_db.creator_id, main_db.cw_id, main_db.supplier FROM main_db; WHERE creator_id LIKE ' * " & Me.txtKeywords & " * ' "
```

A semi-colon is a line terminator, meaning the “end of the SQL statement.”

Final statement:

```
SQL = "SELECT main_db.creator_id, main_db.cw_id, main_db.supplier FROM main_db WHERE creator_id LIKE ' * " & Me.txtKeywords & " * ' "
```